# Clear CSS added by TagBuilder AddCssClass MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a tagbuilder , I added css to the tag like this:

```
td.AddCssClass("Center");
```

now I need to clear all the css that has been applied to the tagbuilder.

what is the best way of clearing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
tb.Attributes["class"] = string.Empty
```

tb is your TagBuilder.